# ServletException while configuring the tiles in spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Hi I am trying to configure the tiles 2 framework in in spring 3.2.8 but I am getting the following exception

```
Aug 28, 2014 11:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/emr_analytics] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'menu' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'menu' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my tiles.xml is given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/pages/mainTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/pages/menu.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="createUser" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="welcome to Floating Doctor"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/user.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition> 
</tiles-definitions>
```

my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sonata.controller" />

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView" 
        /> <property name="prefix" value="/" /> <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property> 
        </bean> -->

    <!-- <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  
        <property name="viewClass">  
            <value>  
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView  
        </value>  
        </property>  
      </bean> 

       <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">  
        <property name="definitions">  
            <list>  
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  
       </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller is given below,

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String password) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        String result = EmrService.login(username, password);
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("menu");
        /*
         * ArrayList<Users> userlist = EmrService.getUsers();
         * modelAndView.addObject("userlist", userlist);
         */

        return modelAndView;

    }
```

I have went through same problem in stack overflow site but I didn't get.
Guys please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have menu.jsp page in pages folder?

Comment: I have already added the menu.jsp in tiles.xml and it is present in WEB-INF/pages folder but still I getting the exception.

Comment: @Mukesh try adding this in `tiles.xml` , since you are returning view `menu` from your `controller`

`<definition name="menu">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Menu"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/menu.jsp"></put-attribute>
  </definition>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver` by passing view to be resolved using  `tiles`

So when spring return back from your `Login` method, it tries to find the the view with name `menu` in your `tiles.xml` file which at present is missing from your `tiles definition (tiles.xml)` file.

So please try adding a `tiles definition (tiles.xml)` for `menu` to resolve this problem.

Comment: I have already added the menu.jsp in tiles.xml and it is present in WEB-INF/pages folder but still I getting the exception.

Comment: @Mukesh Please post your `tiles.xml` also and complete stacktrace if not done already